# Does healing self-damage contribute to a healer's ult charge?

Tags: overwatch

Let's say you're playing Mercy and your Pharah damages herself with her rockets until she's almost dead. Then, once the round starts, you start healing her. Does it help you build up ult charge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, only healing damage inflicted by enemies will help charge up an ultimate ability.